# Maximum Theoretical Potential Difference

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

I came across [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111657/is-there-a-maximum-possible-voltage) question. The accepted answer states that:

> Yes, there is a theoretical maximum potential difference. It is the potential difference as dictated by the Pauli exclusion principle; i.e. no two particles may exist in the same state at the same time. This limits the density of electrons that you can have in the universe and, conversely, the maximum potential difference.

Is this answer correct? Can someone explain it a little further? The voltage generated in the extreme case that the answer mentions is in what order of magnitude?

Comment: You might as well ask: What is the maximum temperature?

Comment: The Fermi exclusion principle doesn't put a hard cap on the density (unless space is discrete). It does mean extra electrons have to fill higher energy levels so it costs more energy to pack the electrons together than you'd expect from just the electric potential and capacitance. The author of that answer is not an expert but is just speculating in a way that sounds authoritative.

Comment: The answer doesn't really make sense, I wouldn't take it too seriously.